# How to display small hint(message) in the bottom middle of the screen in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, user-interface, material-design

On Android(I don't know what about IOS), you can sometimes see small light grey rounded box with a message appearing in the bottom center of the screen. Like the "Volume is off" in the Google Translator app. I've seen this feature in many of the other applications so I think it is included in the material design. Is there an implementation of this feature in the Flutter framework?

[image]

Comment: Check this: https://pub.dev/packages/fluttertoast

Answer (score 2):

I think the package [fluttertoast](https://pub.dev/packages/fluttertoast) is what you are looking for. Here is a quick example on how you could use it :

**Code**

```dart
class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(title: Text(widget.title)),
      body: Center(
        child: RaisedButton(
          child: Text('Show toast'),
          onPressed: () => Fluttertoast.showToast(
            msg: "This is a short message",
            toastLength: Toast.LENGTH_SHORT,
            textColor: Colors.black,
            fontSize: 16,
            backgroundColor: Colors.grey[200],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

**Screenshot**

[image]